# My stored procedure doesn't update when the button is clicked

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Here is my stored procedure that does the update and when I test the procedure using SQL Server it works perfectly.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [TKSFlex].[UpdateComment]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
  @Comment char(50),
  @Employee char(25)
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
 -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
 -- interfering with SELECT statements.
 SET NOCOUNT On;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here

 Update whiteboard set Comment = @Comment 
 where Employee = @Employee

COMMIT
```

And here is the code executed when the update button is clicked

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal es System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click

    InputsModule.Employee = "'Mathe BF'"
    Objconn.Open()

    dbcommand.Connection = Objconn

    dbcommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    dbcommand.CommandText = "[TKSFlex].[UpdateComment]"

    dbcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment", txtComment.Text)
    dbcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee", InputsModule.Employee)

    'dbcommand.Parameters.Add("@Comment", SqlDbType.Char).Value = txtComment.Text
    'dbcommand.Parameters.Add("@Employee", SqlDbType.Char).Value = InputsModule.Employee
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    Try
        i = dbcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MsgBox("failed")
    End Try

    Objconn.Close()
End Sub
```

By the table doesn't get updated when the query is executed and an Exception doesn't get thrown, which implies the the code does get executed but no modification is made to the database, I'm just not sure where I went wrong

Comment: You need to define **a length** for any character parameters - e.g. use this: `dbcommand.Parameters.Add("@Comment", SqlDbType.Char, 50).Value = txtComment.Text` - otherwise, your parameter is **just one character long**!

Answer (score 2):

The most logical cause is:

```
InputsModule.Employee = "'Mathe BF'"
```

That should probably be:

```
InputsModule.Employee = "Mathe BF"
```

The parameter will be quoted for you by ADO.NET.  Putting the quotes in manually will result in a search for quote-mathe bf-quote, which probably does not exist :)

Answer (score 0):

for add with value u need to specify the type of the parameter as shown in below code.

`SqlParameter parameter = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("paramName", value);
parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;`

Comment: The data type is inferred from the value.  For `input` parameters, there's usually no need to specify the data type explicitly.